# Check interval between two dates

Tags: sql-server, date, intervals

I have a table with time intervals from date `a` to date `b`. The intervals are in 30 minutes like this:

```
2021-02-22 00:00:00.000
2021-02-22 00:30:00.000
2021-02-22 01:00:00.000
2021-02-22 01:30:00.000
2021-02-22 02:00:00.000
2021-02-22 02:30:00.000
2021-02-22 03:00:00.000
[...]
2021-03-21 23:30:00.000
```

I have to check if there are records every 30 minutes from my `MIN(date) = 2021-02-22 00:00:00.000` to my `MAX(date) = 2021-03-21 23:30:00.000`.

The `COUNT()` for the records for every calendar week is `336`. 30 Minutes per day * 7 days a week = (24 * 2) * 7).
I tried to check if there are 336 records for every calendar week but if one record is missing and one exists twice, the count is 336, but the result is wrong.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
         SELECT a,
                b,
                DATEPART(iso_week, interval_datetime) AS cw,
                COUNT(id)                             AS counts
         FROM data_table
         GROUP BY DATEPART(iso_week, interval_datetime),
                  a,
                  b
     ) AS xyz
WHERE counts <> 336;
```

Is there another way to check if there are double records and check if every 30 minute record is used? Maybe without a "date"-table.

Thanks!

Comment: Does every 30 minutes mean not more than 30 min between records, or that every 30 min starting from 00:00 midnight has a record? I.e. is it ok to have 00:15 and 00:50 and 01:25?

Comment: just times from 00:00 and then every 30 minutes until 00:00 again and so on. cheers!

Comment: Is that my first option or second option?

Comment: not more than 30 min between records and every 30 min starting from 00:00 midnight has a record

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(CHECK_TIME) AS
(
   SELECT '2021-02-22 00:00:00.000'
      UNION ALL
   SELECT'2021-02-22 00:30:00.000'
      UNION ALL
   SELECT'2021-02-22 01:00:00.000'
     UNION ALL
   SELECT'2021-02-22 01:30:00.000'
     UNION ALL
   SELECT'2021-02-22 02:00:00.000'
     UNION ALL
   SELECT'2021-02-22 02:30:00.000'
     UNION ALL
   SELECT'2021-02-22 03:00:00.000'
     UNION ALL
   SELECT '2021-02-22 03:18:00.000'--FAIL ROW
     UNION ALL
   SELECT'2021-02-22 03:00:00.000'--DOUBLED RECORD
  )
 SELECT C.CHECK_TIME,LAG(CHECK_TIME)OVER(ORDER BY C.CHECK_TIME)LAGG,
    ABS(DATEDIFF(MI,C.CHECK_TIME,LAG(CHECK_TIME)OVER(ORDER BY C.CHECK_TIME)))AS         MINUTES_DIFFERENCE
  FROM CTE AS C
```

Could you please check if this approach helps to isolate problematic records. I post it as answer because it is too long for acomment

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEAD` to get the next value, then filter so that it returns all values where the gap is too large

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
         SELECT a,
                b,
                interval_datetime,
                LEAD(interval_datetime) OVER (ORDER BY interval_datetime) AS nextInterval
         FROM data_table
     ) AS t
WHERE nextInterval IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(second, interval_datetime, nextInterval) > 1800;
```